# Unable to understand why the constant x is compared to a negative constant y in a where clause within a switch case

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm learning and going through the control flow section in the Swift documentation. I've across a chunk of code that I don't understand. My question is why on line 5, the constant value of y is set to negative within the where clause.

```
let yetAnotherPoint = (1, -1)
switch yetAnotherPoint {
case let (x, y) where x == y:
  print("(\(x), \(y)) is on the line x == y")
case let (x, y) where x == -y:
  print("(\(x), \(y)) is on the line x == -y")
case let (x, y):
  print("(\(x), \(y)) is just some arbitrary point")
}
// Prints "(1, -1) is on the line x == -y"
```

Comment: It's not set to negative, you are comparing the opposite of its value. --1 => +1 in maths. So 1 is equal to 1.

Comment: It's a switch statement around the possible values x and y could assume. Line 5 captures a case when x equal to -y, e.g. x=1 and y=-1, or x=-10 and y=10. The print statement below serves as the explanation of the case.

Comment: if it is to compare the temporary constants with the tuple, why not directly compare it rather than setting y to -y. Sorry if this is going over my head.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, Larme has answered by question. Thank you for your help and time.